# I want to write a script that replaces all $$ ... $$ math formulas with \ [... \] in texstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, scripts

Ask people to help me write a script that replaces all the math formulas $$ ... $$ into \ [... ] in texstudio.
Thank you!

Comment: Latexindent can help with this, see https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-replacements.html#lst-displaymath

Comment: You can use function replace (Ctrl + R) in TeXstudio or TeXmaker.

Comment: I want to replace large numbers of files so manually Ctrl + R is not suitable

Comment: That seems difficult

Comment: You could use Geany, `ctrl + H` finds all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways that might help to get you started.

We'll start with the following file, say `myfile.tex`:

## `myfile.tex`

```
before text $$a^2+b^2=4$$ and $$c^2$$

$$
d^2+e^2 = f^2
$$
and also $$ g^2
$$ and some inline math: $h^2$
```

in each of the following, the output is:

## `output.tex`

```
before text \[a^2+b^2=4\] and \[c^2\]

\[
d^2+e^2 = f^2
\]
and also \[ g^2
\] and some inline math: $h^2$
```

## option 1: a perl one liner

```
perl -p0 -e 's/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/\\\[$1\\\]/sg' myfile.tex > output.tex
```

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html, for example, for details of perl switches.

## option 2: using a perl script

Using the following script, and the command

```
perl replace.pl myfile.tex > output.tex
```

## `replace.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# read the file into the Document body
my @lines;
my $fileName = $ARGV[0];

# if the file exists, read it into an array
if(-e $fileName){
    open(MAINFILE, $fileName) or die "Could not open input file, $fileName";
    push(@lines,$_) while(<MAINFILE>);
    close(MAINFILE);
} 

# join the lines up
my $body = join("",@lines);

# make the substitution
$body =~ s/\$\$
           (.*?)
           \$\$/\\\[$1\\\]/sgx;

# output the body
print $body;

exit(0);
```

### option 3: using `latexindent`

Using [`latexindent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en) which should be available as part of your `LaTeX` distribution, you can use the following YAML settings file:

### `Anh.yaml`

```
replacements:
  -
    substitution: |-
     s/\$\$
       (.*?)
       \$\$/\\\[$1\\\]/sgx
```

and then call it with

```
latexindent.pl -rr -l=Anh.yaml myfile.tex -o=output.tex
```

Comment: Not so simple. You have to handle cases like `For $x$$=$$y$, we have no displays`.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau an interesting test case... I wonder: is it realistic...? Also, you'll note that my post said `help get you started`...

Comment: to whoever gave -1: thanks!